# Ionic ngElse equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to do a simple if else in Angular template. I'm using Ionic framework. What I want to do is something like

```
if (val != null){
  document.write("No value");
}
else{
  document.write("Has value");
}
```

What I have now is

```
<ion-grid *ngIf="devices">
  <!-- Show if devices exist -->
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          device 1
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<ion-grid>
  <!-- Show if devices DO NOT exist -->
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button text-center ion-button round col-6 offset-3> Odśwież urządznia </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I wanted to do something like `*ngIf!=null` or `*ngElse` but these two do not work.

So my question is how do I do that?

Comment: Why is *ngif='!devices' not working.... Is the variable devices boolean type if yes it should work

Comment: Try setting a boolean type variable and check when value is null set it as false and when not null true and then use inside html

Comment: I tried `*ngIf != 'devices'` Your option works great. Can you explain how it works, or post a link to the right docs? Does the condition go into the quotes? It's new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use in following way -

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
   Truthy condition
</div>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  False condition
</ng-template>
```

hope this will help you, let me know in case any issue?

Comment: Is there a way not to use the `ng-template`? Other than that it works great